# aws command line works but cannot get boto equivilent

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have a bucket with a subfolder `ABC`. The ACL has been set so my given access keys can only upload to the subfolder `ABC`

The following command line works

```
aws s3 cp local-file-name s3://my-bucket/ABC/
```

I'm trying to do the equivalent from boto

```
conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_access_key)
b = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket')
k = Key(b)
k.key = 'ABC/Hello'
k.set_contents_from_string("Hello World")
print (k.get_contents_from_string())
```

> boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

I know this is ACL related as when I swap the keys to a set with full access It works.

So why with the restricted keys the command line will work but boto will not ?

Do I need to give the restricted keys list access to the bucket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, boto tries to validate the bucket by performing a `HEAD` request during the `get_bucket` call.  That will fail for your scenario so tell boto to skip this validation step:

```
b = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket', validate=False)
```